# control both start and end of while loop using variable in windows bat script

Tags: windows, batch-file

I can do a while loop in DOS batch file like this:

```
@REM initialize test value to be "true"
@SET intCounter=1

:while

@REM test condition
@IF %intCounter% GTR 10 (GOTO wend)

@REM procedure where condition is "true"
@echo %intCounter%

@REM set new test value
@SET /a intCounter=intCounter+1

@REM loop
@GOTO while

:wend

@PAUSE
```

This will loop ten times. 
My question are two folds.

1. How can I also control the end of the loop. I tried set end =1 and replace 10 with %end%, this does not work.
2. How to read input from keyboard and set them into iniCounter and end.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know what you did, but

```
@set end=5
:while
@IF %intCounter% GTR %end% (GOTO wend)
```

does work,or

```
@set /p end="Enter the end:"
```

if you want it to be entered by the user

And since your question is tagged 'windows', you might be better off with

```
set /p start="From:"
set /p end="To:"
for /l %%i in (%start%, 1, %end%) do (
    echo %%i
)
```

Comment: Thanks. I will try it now and mark the answer if I am successful.

Comment: 'code'@set end=5
'code':while
'code'@IF %intCounter% GTR %end% (GOTO wend)

works best for me result. I don't know why. I used exact same code. May be just typo or the keyboard. The other one's output is a bit wired. like c:\()1  then c:\()2. ...